# Prevent dependencies being required by other projects

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, dependencies

I am writing a project which will encapsulate multiple Calendar APIs (Google Calendar, Outlook ect) in one service. This will allow me to integrate different APIs which can be mapped to our domain model. However I am having issues with required dependencies *spilling over* into other projects. Here's an example:

I have created a generic class which does most of the work and conversions from the API model to *our* model. Here's an example:

```
public abstract class CalendarAPIBase<TEventType> : ICalendarAPI
{
    public CalendarEvent Get(string id)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("id");

        return Convert(GetEvent(id));
    }

    public List<CalendarEvent> GetAll()
    {
        List<CalendarEvent> result = new List<CalendarEvent>();

        List<TEventType> es = GetAllEvents();

        foreach (TEventType e in es)
            result.Add(Convert(e));

        return result;
    }

    protected abstract List<TEventType> GetAllEvents();
    protected abstract CalendarEvent Convert(TEventType obj);

    //More stuff below.
}
```

So this is a beautiful thing, anything that inherits `CalendarAPIBase` doesn't have to do much work other than **getting** the data from the API, the base class will handle the conversions.

Ok, so here's where things go wrong. I have created a `GoogleCalendarAPI` class, which inherits from `CalendarAPIBase`. It passes in the `Event` class, which belongs to a NuGet package `Google.Apis.Calendar.v3`.

```
public class GoogleCalendarAPI : CalendarAPIBase<Event>
```

The problem here is that this class is exposing the `Event` class, therefore anything that references this project will also need to reference `Google.Apis.Calendar.v3`. Ideally anyone wishing to use this service will only have to reference just the project and not have to worry about installing other NuGet packages.

How can I restructure my classes to prevent this from happening?

Comment: if you are going to distribute your library via NuGet it will resolve dependencies for the users transparently.

Comment: In this scenario, this will not be distributed via NuGet, it's just a single project in our solution that will be referenced by other projects within the same solution.

Comment: No, anything that inherits `CalendarAPIBase` must pass in the an event type. This is simply to encapsulate the main logic in one base class. If it can be structured in a different way to prevent `Event` from being publically exposed, then that would be the end goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward way to resolve this stuff is an [Abstract factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) pattern.

First, you make `CalendarAPIBase<TEventType>` and all its descendants `internal`. All the public stuff has to be concentrated within a public `ICalendarAPI` interface.

Next step is introducing public classes like this:

```
public static class GoogleCalendarAPIFactory 
{
    public static ICalendarAPI Instantiate( ....... ) 
    {
        .......
        return new GoogleCalendarAPI( ..... );
    }
}
```

The factory will make all the `TEventType` hassle hidden ftom the library user, therefore he will not need to add all the packages containing `TEventType` implementations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can avoid referencing 3rd party assemblies if you use classes like **Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Event** directly in your code.

However, you can use [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx) to merge 3rd party API into your own, that way the dependencies of your assemblies will be deployed along with your assemblies.

I usually use ILMerge in the post build event.
For example:

- After GoogleCalendarAPI project is built, merge **GoogleCalendarAPI.dll** and **Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.dll** and save it in **"GoogleCalendarAPI_location\mergerd\GoogleCalendarAPI.dll"**
- Copy **"GoogleCalendarAPI_location\mergerd\GoogleCalendarAPI.dll"** to the location of the original **GoogleCalendarAPI.dll** and replace it.

Now you've got **GoogleCalendarAPI.dll** with **Google.Apis.Calendar.v3** baked into it.
Now every assembly that references GoogleCalendarAPI.dll gets both.